# How to get the SObject type in LWC JS?

Tags: lightning-web-components

Hello I have an LWC which calls some apex that runs a SOSL search and returns a nested list of accounts and contacts. I'm iterating over the result set and building a single list of records to show in a datatable. The problem i'm having is I need to be able to get the sobject type (Account or Contact) while iterating over the result set and building the datatable data.

note: this is my first LWC so feel free to point out anything im doing wrong or inefficiently. Everything helps me learn.

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import getAccountContactList from '@salesforce/apex/AccountContactSOSLController.getSOSLResultList';

export default class accountContactSearch extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    searchKey;
    searchResults;
    _title;
    message;
    variant;
    loading = false;

    updateSearchKey(event){
        this.searchKey = event.target.value;
        this.param = event.target.value;
    }

    handleSearch () {
        //show the spinner while query is being executed
        this.loading = true;

        //call apex method for SOSL search
        getAccountContactList({pSearchString: this.searchKey})
        .then(resultSOSL=>{
            //build the base url for the record Id
            let baseUrl = 'https://' + location.host + '/';
            this.searchResults=[];

            //show msg if no records found
            if(resultSOSL[0].length > 0 || resultSOSL[1].length > 0){
                //build the datatable records from the result data
                for (let i = 0; i < resultSOSL.length; i++) {
                    for(let j = 0; j < resultSOSL[i].length; j++){
                        let resultItem = resultSOSL[i][j];
                        this.searchResults.push({Name: resultItem.Name, RecType: '[GET SOBJECTTYPE HERE]', RecUrl: baseUrl + resultItem.Id });
                    }
                }
            }else{
                this._title = 'Search Results';
                this.message = 'No records have been found.';
                this.variant = 'info';
                this.showNotification();
            }            
            //hide spinner
            this.loading = false;
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            this.searchResults = null;
            this.loading = false;
            this._title = 'Search Error';
            this.message = error.body.message;
            this.variant = 'error';
            this.showNotification();
        });
    }

    //define the datatable columns
    cols = [
        {label: 'Record Name', fieldName: 'Name',    type:'text'},
        {label: 'Record Type', fieldName: 'RecType', type:'text'},
        {label: 'Click To Open', fieldName: 'RecUrl',    type:'url', typeAttributes: { label: 'View', target: '_blank'}},
    ]

    //shows a toast msg with custom values
    showNotification() {
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: this._title,
            message: this.message,
            variant: this.variant,
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to post the answer I found for this problem. The solution, in the end, was quite simple, what I did was JSON.serialize the response SOSL response list:

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static String getSOSLResultList (string pSearchString) {
        //Do SOSL Search based on string filter parameter 
        List<list<SObject>> accountContactSearchList = new List<List<SObject>>();
        String searchQuery = QueryBuilder.AccountSOSLSearchString;
        accountContactSearchList = search.query(searchQuery);
        system.debug('### [getSOSLResultList] accountContactSearchList: ' + accountContactSearchList);
        return JSON.serialize(accountContactSearchList,true);
    }
```

This has the effect of including the object type on the JSON string:

```
if(resultSOSLJson[0].length > 0 || resultSOSLJson[1].length > 0){
    let parsedResultList = JSON.parse(resultSOSLJson);  
    for(let i = 0 ; i < parsedResultList.length ; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < parsedResultList[i].length; j++){
            let resultItem =parsedResultList[i][j];
            this.searchResults.push({Name: resultItem.Name, RecType: resultItem.attributes.type, RecUrl: baseUrl + resultItem.Id, Id: resultItem.Id, Counter: resultItem.Counter__c });
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will help someone with the same issue. thank you @sfdcfox for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever order is specified in the SOSL will be the returned types in the same order. If you want to check the sobjectType, you can check the item in each list:

```
this.searchResults.push({Name: resultItem.Name, RecType: resultItem.sobjectType, RecUrl: baseUrl + resultItem.Id });
```

Note that you really should be using [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) + [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). It's a lot more efficient.

Comment: thank you for your response. I tried   `resultItem.sobjectType` and it did not work. In the end I used an inline if: `RecType: (i == 0 ? 'Account' : 'Contact')` and it worked. I am having issues using the map method to build the list from the nested arrays. Would an example i can use?